# javascript stops working after clicking and loading bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a feature w/ rails + jQuery. i get a collection from the server and format it to display in a div.

The problem I am having, is when i click on any of the bootstrap tabs that are being loaded on that page, all the javascript stops working. For example, the `$(my_element).hide();`, `$(other_elements).on('click', function() {}`, etc all stops working. However, when I refresh the page, even with a url from clicking on a tab like `www.mywebsite.com/u/r/l?page=1&collection_status=Attempted`, works just fine.

From my research, I understand this has to do with how the page is being loaded. My question is, what is the best approach to fix this? I have not found any viable solutions from my research.

Any help is much appreciated.

Here is an example of one of the pieces of JS that stopped working

```
   $('.prospect_select_box').on('click', function() {

        var empty = [].filter.call(checkboxes, function(checkbox) {
          return !checkbox.checked
        });

        if (checkboxes.length == empty.length) {
        $('#prospect_select_all').prop('checked', false);
        $('#prospect-left-section').hide();
        }

        if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('#prospect-left-section').show();
        }   else if ( !$(this).prop('checked') && $('#prospect_select_all').prop('checked') ) {
            $('#prospect-left-section').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: check your browser console, what is the JS error?

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan there are no errors. when clicking through this, I have a clear console

Comment: there must be some JS issue, otherwise all js stops working is not possible

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan i agree. it has to do with clicking on and loading new tabs on the page

Comment: post your `$(other_elements).on('click', function() {}` js code to hide into the question, so that i can find

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan just posted an example piece of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144292/discussion-between-mahesh-singh-chouhan-and-james-n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change your click binding

**like below:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.prospect_select_box', function() {

    var empty = [].filter.call(checkboxes, function(checkbox) {
      return !checkbox.checked
    });

    if (checkboxes.length == empty.length) {
    $('#prospect_select_all').prop('checked', false);
    $('#prospect-left-section').hide();
    }

    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#prospect-left-section').show();
    }   else if ( !$(this).prop('checked') && $('#prospect_select_all').prop('checked') ) {
        $('#prospect-left-section').show();
    }
});
```

When we load html elements into DOM after page loads, then we need to add binding with `document` object to work with current available DOM elements